# linear regression/trend line with ms charting

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mschart, linear-regression

I have data that are numbers both on x and y and have charted them using [mschart 4.0](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

I need to add a trend line/linear regression to a bunch of points I have.  The data on x and y are both numbers (no dates anywhere), for instance (33.4,45.1) would be a point.

In the samples I downloaded from the first link I found a linear regression sample in the code files forecasting.aspx(.cs), and I found this [ms documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456655.aspx)

I have added a linear regression line to the chart with the following line (once all other data it setup etc)

```
Chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.Forecasting, parameters, "Input:Y", "Forecasting:Y,Range:Y,Range:Y2");
```

The problem with both of these is that they assume dates are used.  I went ahead and implemented it anyway, but my regression line starts at around the x value of 20, and will go to an x value of the max x value of one of the points (almost 70) if I give the parameter Period a value of 700.  But since it doesn't start at x value 0 I don't trust it is correct.

Anyone have any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: You can always implement the regression yourself (there are Math libraries out there - matrix math is great here) and add as a new series. What I found with the Chart regression is that it adds their error range (pretty good, but sometimes you don't want to necessarily show that)

Comment: Yes, I obviously can implement it myself or use a third party library, though I don't know of any good third party libraries but would be open to suggestions. If I want to display it in a chart that looks like everything else in this project I have to use mscharts, which right now sounds impossible.

Comment: UPDATE: It has nothing to do with dates.  If I display 150-200 real data points (or even modify the mschart example to generate more data), the best fit line doesn't start and end when the scatterplot does, it is significantly shorter. I am guessing this is a bug with mscharts.

Comment: @flaviotsf - BTW, you can hide the display of error ranges by passing the following options; "Linear,0,false,false" to the formula as seen in the code snippet by Greg

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to add an extra datapoint at the beginning and end of each trendline based on the minimum and maximum x values in the scatterplot.

This can be done by

- calculating the slope of the trendline
- calculating the intercept of the trendline
- getting the minimum x value in the scatterplot
- getting the maximum x value in the scatterplot
- calculating the minimum y value by using the slope, intercept and minimum x value
- calculating the maximum y value by using the slope, intercept and maximum x value
- adding two points with the x and y values to the trendline

The following code snippet adds start and end points to two trendlines followed by simple functions to calculate slope and intercept:

```
       if (Chart1.Series["Budget Year"].Points.Count > 2 &&  Chart1.Series["Actual Last Year"].Points.Count > 2)
        {
            Chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.Forecasting, "Linear,0,false,false", Chart1.Series["Budget Year"], Chart1.Series["Trendline (Budget Year)"]);
            Chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.Forecasting, "Linear,0,false,false", Chart1.Series["Actual Last Year"], Chart1.Series["Trendline (Actual Last Year)"]);

            double budgetSlope = Utility.GetSlope(Chart1.Series["Trendline (Budget Year)"].Points[0], Chart1.Series["Trendline (Budget Year)"].Points[1]);
            double lastYearSlope = Utility.GetSlope(Chart1.Series["Trendline (Actual Last Year)"].Points[0], Chart1.Series["Trendline (Actual Last Year)"].Points[1]);
            double budgetIntercept = Utility.GetIntercept(Chart1.Series["Trendline (Budget Year)"].Points[0], Chart1.Series["Trendline (Budget Year)"].Points[1]);
            double lastYearIntercept = Utility.GetIntercept(Chart1.Series["Trendline (Actual Last Year)"].Points[0], Chart1.Series["Trendline (Actual Last Year)"].Points[1]);
            double minBudgetRevenue = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Select("RevCurrBudget = MIN(RevCurrBudget)")[0]["RevCurrBudget"]);
            double maxBudgetRevenue = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Select("RevCurrBudget = MAX(RevCurrBudget)")[0]["RevCurrBudget"]);
            double minLastYearRevenue = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Select("RevPrevActual = MIN(RevPrevActual)")[0]["RevPrevActual"]);
            double maxLastYearRevenue = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Select("RevPrevActual = MAX(RevPrevActual)")[0]["RevPrevActual"]);
            double minBudgetEBIT = (budgetSlope * minBudgetRevenue) + budgetIntercept;
            double maxBudgetEBIT = (budgetSlope * maxBudgetRevenue) + budgetIntercept;
            double minLastYearEBIT = (lastYearSlope * minLastYearRevenue) + lastYearIntercept;
            double maxLastYearEBIT = (lastYearSlope * maxLastYearRevenue) + lastYearIntercept;

            Chart1.Series["Trendline (Budget Year)"].Points.InsertXY(0, minBudgetRevenue, minBudgetEBIT);
            Chart1.Series["Trendline (Budget Year)"].Points.AddXY(maxBudgetRevenue, maxBudgetEBIT);
            Chart1.Series["Trendline (Actual Last Year)"].Points.InsertXY(0, minLastYearRevenue, minLastYearEBIT);
            Chart1.Series["Trendline (Actual Last Year)"].Points.AddXY(maxLastYearRevenue, maxLastYearEBIT);
        }


public static double GetSlope(DataPoint pt1, DataPoint pt2)
{
    return GetSlope(pt1.XValue, pt1.YValues[0], pt2.XValue, pt2.YValues[0]);
}

public static double GetSlope(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) 
{
    return (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
}

public static double GetIntercept(DataPoint pt1, DataPoint pt2)
{
    double slope = GetSlope(pt1, pt2);
    double y = pt1.YValues[0];
    double x = pt1.XValue;
    return y - (slope * x);
}
```